# Socket error in Java

Tags: java, sockets

We have J2EE Web application deployed on JBOSS 4.0.2 server.
On production we are facing serious issue of socket error. 
we are getting following error.

> java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: recv failed

Due to above socket errors application is not able to connect database.
Restarting jboss application also does not help. To resolve socket error we have to restart production machine.

What could be reason for above socket errors?

Comment: Is your Firewall not blocking the port?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the Firewall.

Comment: This may be better answered on serverfault

Comment: I agree with the firewall theory. The first result on google on "recv" (the key word here) says: *recv Function (Windows) - [Receives data from a connected socket or a bound connectionless socket.]*